# How to repair Corrupted jpeg file that still get their thumbail done correctly?

Tags: data-recovery, corruption, jpeg, thumbnails

I've got a bunch of photos that were on an SD card. 
Most of them are corrupted now, I cannot open them in any program (Gwenview, Gimp, on windows too...) But every file browser still can correctly make most of their thumbnail. for instance : 
[Gwenview with a photo selected that have a correct thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsmQa.png)

I'm aware that the SD card is probably dying, so I already made a dd image of the sd card, on which I can work.

So far, My searches led me to photorec which does not work in my case: it recovered 4 useless photos and as about two/third of my ~400 still have their thumbnail, I still hope to have most of those back.

What Can I do?
Any help appreciated :)

PS: I'm on Kubuntu 20.04, I'm able to be root and I'm not afraid of the command line (but a graphical tool is still handy :D )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked [the very same question on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230879/how-to-repair-corrupted-jpeg-files-that-still-have-their-thumbnails/), here is the best answer I had :)

You can use [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) to recover from the thumbnails. You will only get a low resolution image by doing this but it may be all you can recover if the files are that badly corrupt.

You can install it by putting `sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl` in a terminal window. Then put the following:

```
exiftool -b -ThumbnailImage -w $HOME/recovered/%f_thumb.%e -ext JPG <input directory>
```

where `<input directory>` is the path to the corrupt photos.

The above command will attempt to extract the thumbnails from the JPEG photos that have a readable thumbnail to a directory called `recovered` in your user home directory.

There's also many recovery tools (mostly paid) that can be found by searching online that attempt to repair the whole image but the vast majority don't really work. One of the few that may work is [JPEG Repair Shop](http://anderspedersen.net/jpegrepair/) (free) but it's manual so can take a long time if you have lots of corrupt photos. It's also only available for Windows.